# Задание сложного условия if в Python

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать правильно такое условие в одной строке:

```
if (g%2=0 and g1%2=0 and v%2=0 and v1%2=0) or (g%2!=0 and g1%2!=0 and v%2!=0 and v1%2!=0):
```

Comment: У вас присваивание, а не сравнение, замените `=` на `==`, должны заменить на: 
`(g%2==0 and g1%2==0 and v%2==0 and v1%2==0)`

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле, я не рекомендую писать такое в одну строчку. Когда это будет читать другой программист (или вы сами через несколько месяцев), разбираться в таком коде будет сложно.

Лучше разбить сложное условие на несколько проверок.

Кроме того, почти всегда проверку числа на равенство нулю лучше заменить на использование самого числа как готового логического выражения.

Поскольку ноль эквивалентен False, а любое ненулевое число эквивалентно True,

`num` можно использовать вместо `num != 0`

`not num` можно использовать вместо `num == 0`

Длинный цепочки одинаковых операторов 'and' или 'or' лучше заменять на функции all() и any().

Таким образом, я бы рекомендовал вам переписать ваш код так:

```
check1 = not any([g % 2, g1 % 2, v % 2, v1 % 2])
check2 = all([g % 2, g1 % 2, v % 2, v1 %2])

if check1 or check2:
  # some code
```

Этот код можно ещё улучшить. Другие участники сообщества уже указали вам на то, что повторяющиеся вычисления можно вычислить один раз, и потом уже готовый результат использовать столько раз, сколько нужно.

В другой ситуации я бы то же посоветовал вам так сделать.

Но у вас всё ещё забавнее.

Поскольку остаток от деления на два может быть только либо 1, либо 0, а вы хотите проверить, что либо все четыре остатка равны нулю, либо все не равны, то ваше условие можно заменить таким:

```
if (g % 2) == (g1 % 2) == (v % 2) == (v1 % 2):
    # some code
```

Читается достаточно легко, и все остатки вычисляются только по одному разу.

Comment: `(g % 2) == (g1 % 2) == (v % 2) == (v1 % 2)` - красиво!

Comment: @MaxU, Спасибо :)

Comment: Для неокрепших питоновских умов можно еще удалить скобки... 8-D

Comment: @MaxU, тогда чтобы оно всё не сливалось, придётся нахождение остатка писать слитно, как было у топикстартера - g1%2 А это не очень хорошо. Уж пусть лучше неокрепшие умы сразу к хорошему стилю приучаются :)

Comment: а почему это работает?) Мне вот например всегда казалось, что == выполняется слева направо, а что оно приводит результат сравнения к булевскому. Т.е.  1==0==0==1 будет  правда (1==0 = 0) (0 == 0 = 1) (1 == 1 = 1).

Comment: @pavel в большинстве других языков не работает, в Python - работает. Почему - потому что решили что так удобнее и реализовали работу сравнений более по-человечески)

Comment: @pavel в питоне объединять в цепочки можно и другие операторы сравнения. Например, a < b < c < d тоже будет работать так, как можно ожидать с точки зрения математики.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы записать условие в одной строке:

```
same_parity = (a & 1) == (b & 1) == (c & 1) == (d & 1)
if same_parity:
    # ...
```

а ещё лучше использовать имя подходящее под вашу конкретную задачу, к примеру:

```
if can_access_foombulator:
    # ...
```

Ниже описано как ещё можно `can_access_foombulator` вычислить.

---

Если вы видите в коде переменные типа `g`, `g1`, `g2`, `g3`, ..., `gn`, это значит что вместо этого вам можно использовать одно имя `g`, ссылающуюся на всю коллекцию сразу. К примеру, вместо:

```
g, g1, g2 = 0, 1, 2
```

используйте:

```
g = 0, 1, 2
```

или

```
g = [0, 1, 2]
```

если вы хотите изменить `g` позже. Аналогично для `v`, `v1`, etc.

Также, вероятно в вашем случае следует использовать более описательные имена чем `g`, `v`.

---

Таблица истинности для условия *"all even" or "all odd"* совпадает с [XNOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate):

```
A B XNOR
0 0 1  # all even
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 1  # all odd
```

для битов это совпадает с равенством, то есть:

```
can_access_foombulator = all_equal(*lsb)  # all_equal = xnor
```

где LSB это [Least Significant Bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit):

```
lsb = [n & 1 for n in [g, g1, v, v1]]
```

и

```
def all_equal(*bits):
    return all(bits) or not any(bits)
```

Альтернативные реализации:

```
def all_equal(*items):
    return all(items[0] == x for x in items)

def all_equal(*items):
    return items.count(items[0]) == len(items)
```

См. [check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical).

Comment: Кстати отличный совет использовать конструкции: `g = 0, 1, 2` или `g = [0, 1, 2]` - такие коллекции потом гораздо легче и элегантнее обрабатывать

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
values = [g, g1, v, v1]
if all(val%2==0 for val in values) or all(val%2!=0 for val in values):
```

> Обратите внимание, что у вас в первом условии неверно проставлен оператор сравнения:
>
> ==

Comment: в этом случае val%2 выполнится в обоих проверках, те дважды

Comment: и !=0 или тут лишние, тк all сам возьмет bool

Answer (score 1):

тк есть несколько проверок * % 2, чтобы не вычислять их для каждой проверки заново, можно сначала сохранить результат в res, а потом уже проверять

```
args = g, g1, v, v1 = 3, 3, 3, 3

check = lambda a: a % 2
res = list(map(check, args))
if all(res) or not any(res):
    print(True)

# или так
from functools import reduce
if reduce(lambda x, y: bool(x % 2) is bool(y % 2), args):
    print(True)

# или так
if all(a % 2 for a in args) or not any(a % 2 for a in args):
    print(True)
```

Comment: 1- Имена  могут код более читаемым сделать. Например, вместо `check` можно `is_odd` или `parity` имя использовать. А в целом условие определяет равны ли младшие биты в заданных числах (все имеют одинаковую чётность). Функцию `all_equal(bits)` или `same_parity(ints)` можно назвать. 2- Решение с reduce() сломано. Попробуйте `args = 0, 0, 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Завести функцию с говорящим названием и её вызвать от аргументов.

```
def xor_like_function(*args):
    all_even = all(t%2 == 0 for t in args)
    all_odd = all(t%2 == 1 for t in args)
    return all_even or all_odd

if xor_like_function(g, g1, v, v1):
    pass
```

Ещё неплохо подумать над хорошими именами для переменных g, g1, v, v1.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяем четность первого элемента, дальше проверяем каждый следующий элемент на четность с предыдущим.
Если элементы по четности разные, возвращается False.

```
def all_even_or_odd(data):
    n = data[0]%2
    for line in data:
        if line % 2 != n:
            return False
    return True

numbers = [g, g1, v, v1]

if all_even_or_odd(numbers):
    # Ваш код
```