# Проверка на соответствие нескольким условиям

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каким способом лучше всего сделать проверку на несколько условий? Например здесь:

```
if (name in line) and (age in line) and (string in text):
    do_something()
```

Если способов несколько, то хотелось бы узнать, где и когда их лучше применять.

Comment: Эффективность различных способов будет зависеть от контекста конкретной задачи. Например иногда эффективнее  будет воспользоваться `all([x in line for x in search_words_list])`, в других случаях проверить пересечение множеств (`set intersection`) и т.д.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Задание сложного условия if в Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/619230/23044)

Comment: @MaxU: скобочки `[]` вы напрасно поставили—это изменяет смысл выражения (`if stack and stack[0] == value`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать all() для случаев, когда нужно чтобы выполнялись все условия из перечисленных и any(), когда нужно чтобы выполнялось хотя бы одно.

Например, ваш код можно переписать таким образом:

```
if all([(name in line), (age in line), (string in text)]):
    do_something()
```

Это можно сделать более удобным, если сначала сформировать массив из условий, а потом передать его в if:

```
checks = [name in line, age in line]
checks.append(string in text)

if all(checks):
    do_something()
```

Как видно из этого кода, массив можно формировать постепенно, добавляя условия в разных местах кода, что может быть полезно, когда нужно формировать список условий динамически в зависимости от разных внешних факторов.

Кроме того, в функциях иногда просто проверяют каждое условие отдельным if, а если условие не проходит(или наоборот проходит - в зависимости от задачи), то прерывают дальнейшее выполнение через return:

```
def foo():

  if not(name in line):
    return False

  if not(age in line):
    return False

  if not(string in text):
    return False

  return True
```

Comment: Можно-то многое, но чем это хорошо, я не понял. Это про any и all.

Comment: @Qwertiy предположим, у нас есть долгая цепочка `A and B and C and D or E and F...`. В неё закралось `or`. Есть шансы его не заметить. А с `all()` таких шансов нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy ещё плюс — это более гибкий способ, он позволяет не знать заранее, сколько условий мы проверяем.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не согласен с первым пунктом. Да и со вторым тоже - мы вычисляем все условия, а потом проверяем, что все были истинны. В большинстве случаев это нелогично.

Comment: @NickVolynkin если нет готового iterable, то all([a,b,c]) неправильно: нет  short-circuit поведения, менее красиво выглядит и менее эффективно по сравнению с `(a and b and c)` (разбитому на несколько строк, если необходимо). То есть пример из вопроса ухудшен применением all(). По хорошему, вопрос следует закрыть как слишком общий: где-то явно надо условия писать, где-то можно all() использовать, где-то следует Ахо-Корасика алгоритм задействовать (чтобы множество слов одновременно в тексте искать), для других данных какие-то другие алгоритмы—от конкретной задачи зависит—очень многие задачи есть

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос очень уж,общий.
Все,собственно,зависит от задачи, к примеру, если у вас нужно проверить гипотезу Сиракуз, то вы применяете цикл `for`,и операторы  `if`или`else`или`elif`.
Если задача требует ветвлений в алгоритме, то просто логические операторы, если
многочисленной проверки условий то используйте циклы.

Comment: `Все,собственно,зависит от задачи` - именно так

Answer (score 2):

```
text = '''1234\n567890'''
line = '567890'
keys = name, age, string = '5', '6', '78'

# чем больше ключей в keys, тем длиннее запись условия ...and...
if (name in line) and (age in line) and (string in line):
    print(1)

# теперь длина условия не зависит от кол-ва keys
check1 = [k in line for k in keys]

if all(check1):  # all для ...and... | any для ...or...
    print(2)

# несколько разных условий можно объединить с помощью chain
from itertools import chain
check2 = string in text, line+age not in text

if all(chain(check1, check2)):
    print(3)

# или так
if all(chain((k in line for k in keys), (string in text, line+age not in text))):
    print(4)

# если условие сложное, его можно вынести в отдельную функцию
def checker(key):
    return key in line or True  # "сложное" условие
# а при проверке использовать map
if all(map(checker, keys)):
    print(5)
```